# Is there a limit on number of paths in firebase multi-path updates?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How many different paths are allowed inside a multi-path update. (maximum)

What is the ideal number of different paths that can be used for simultaneous updation without causing any issues/warnings.

Basically to summarize it all .... how many locations can be simultaneously written before firebase can no longer handle it.

I am looking to run a script which resets various paths.. The number of locations can be a huge number... to optimize this operation, i was thinking of using the multi location update for handling this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running a script which performs a huge number of queries, Multi-path updates are exactly what you need. Don't forget that multi-path updates are atomic operations (all or nothing) which means that if 1 of the operations doesn't succeed, all the other will be cancelled.

Now when it comes to number of updates, there is no limit. You can add as many paths as you want.

One last warning: Make sure all of the paths are corect and the value you're updating is the one you **really** want to update. Many developers (beginners and experts) sometimes make mistakes when specifying the paths and often end up deleting the whole database or a good part of it ends up with data that belongs to another node.

Comment: Thanks buddy... Ya i always go for the patch update with fully qualified path ;) avoids the overwrite risk... But anyway it's good that i can add as many paths as i need... Saves me a ton of network calls

Comment: Btw are you sure that there's no limit? Can you point me to a source or doc which points to this?

Comment: @Kushan: there is no documented limit. There is probably a physical limit and definitely a reasonable limit, but nothing in the code (as far as I know).